# Storing a String in an Enum object in java

Tags: java, database, string, enums

I have this enum Category ,a Question class, a database where question ,option, category,etc are stored.
Question class has its getter() and setter()
My question is how I can  store a string type data from database  in a Category type?
 rs.getString("Cateogory") returns a string but i want to store this string in a category type obj. how can i do so?

```
public enum Category {
Geography,History,GK,Science;
```

}

```
public class Question  {
private int srno;
private String question;
private String option1;
private String option2;
private String option3;
private String option4;
private String correctAns;
private Category Category;
private Complexity complexity;

public Question() {
}

Class X{
    ResultSet rs=null;
    Statement stmt=null;
    List<Question> quesList=new ArrayList<Question>();
    Question q=new Question();
    Category c=null;
    // some code here .....
    while(rs.next())
    {
               q.setQuestion(rs.getString("Question"));
               q.setOption1(rs.getString("optionA"));
               q.setOption2(rs.getString("optionB"));
               q.setOption3(rs.getString("optionC"));
               q.setOption4(rs.getString("OptionD"));
               // But how do i store a Category type?
               quesList.add(q);
    }
}
```

Comment: Make `Category` a `Class` instead of an `Enum`...

Comment: Why? Aren't the category strings in the database exactly the same as the category constants in your enum?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Every enum has a static `valueOf()` method, that takes the name of an enum constant (`"Geography"` for example), and returns the corresponding enum constant (`Category.Geography` for example).

So you just need

```
Category category = Category.valueOf(rs.getString(someIndex));
```